PostgreSQL replication with barman
I have been trying to make a barman replication work for an entire week. Everything is working, both the PostgreSQL and barman servers (not really servers, they are LXC containers) are communicating well. When I do a barman check <database>, everything is OK, when I do a barman backup <database>, everything is working according to the logs and the standard output.
However, after I do the backup, I drop my database and recreate it empty, then I do a remote recovery. When I do the barman recover command, everything seems to work. But when I start postgresql again in the other container to check if the content of the database has been restored, it is still empty, and I don't understand why, as everything is telling me that the recovery worked.

PostgreSQL version: 15
Barman version: 3.4.0
OS: Debian 12
Underlying infrastructure: LXC containers

I was expecting for the content of the database to be restored, but it is still empty.

barman recover is a complicated command with multiple mandatory arguments.  Also "drop my database and recreate it empty" could mean many different things.  Please show us what you actually did, there is not enough detail here for us to know.

Sure no problem : let's call my server with the postgresql pg and the one with barmn backup, just like the barman documentation. What I do is : 1. Create my database with createdb test and I insert random data in a test table. 2. I do a barman check pg (everything is OK). 3. I do a barman backup pg to do a full backup of the database. There again, I have no error message. 4. Then on the postgresql server, I drop the datbase with dropdb test, and re-create it with createdb test. 5. Then I stop my postgresql service with systemctl stop postgresql.


Finally, I recover the database with barman recover --remote-ssh-command="ssh postgres@pg" pg <backup ID> /var/lib/postgresql/15/main. Then I start the postgresql service with systemctl start postgresql, and then if I look inside my database by logging in with psql test and by doing a "SELECT * FROM ", the table doesn't exist, even though the barman recover command went well...


Barman doesn't intuit what you are trying to do.  You have a to tell it.
It assumes you want to restore the system to the latest available point, and that latest available point includes the dropping of the database.  So it restores it to a point where the database has already been dropped.
If you want it to do PITR to the point before the drop, you need to tell it that.
There is no particularly easy way to figure this out, unless you happened to write down the exact moment you screwed up.  You could use pg_waldump to try to find the fateful record.
